# Including PHP files for json application

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

Trying to execute **tleft** in another file, using ajax.

But it is not showing any result.

Tried:

```
<?php
require_once '../class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$reg = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT COUNT(Sr) AS Sr FROM students");
$reg->execute();
$reg_rst = $reg->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$registered= ($reg_rst['Sr']);
echo json_encode([
  'tleft' => $registered
]);
?>
```

When I remove **require_once '../class.user.php';** it gives me result.

Comment: Maybe that file has got syntax errors

Comment: @Akintunde No,  `class.user.php` does not have any error!

Comment: check under network tab in developer tools you may find the root cause of it.

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal No cause found!

Comment: Have you tried running this page manually from a browser?

Comment: @NigelRen yes, it gives: `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="favicon/android-chrome-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="favicon/manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2d89ef">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="favicon/mstile-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">{"registered":"23"}`

Comment: @AkshayMandale Are there any errors in PHP `error_log` file?

Comment: @camelsWriteInCamelCase No, there are no errors in `error_log` file.

Comment: @AkshayMandale There must be errors or JSON encoded data in browser console (Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome -> Network tab -> XHR). Check the request data and request/response headers.